# Four circles & a square in a circle

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, circles

[image]

Radius of the big triangle is $2$. ABCD is a square. What is the difference between $T_{1}$ and $(M_{1}+M_{2})$.
I have solved it already though I don't know if my answer is right or wrong.  My solution is very long.  Is there any short/quick/easy method to solve this problem?  Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Area of ALS=$\frac{\prod}{8}$
area of $X_{1}$ = (area of ALD-area of ALS)
          = $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\prod}{8}$
Area of $M_{1}$ =(area of ALD-(area of $X_{1}$+area of $X_{2}$))
          = $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{4- \prod}{4}$
Area of $(M_{1}+M_{2})$ = $\frac{\prod - 2}{2}$
Area of small triangles=A+C+D+B
                       =$2\prod+4$
Area of $T_{1}$ = $\frac{(\prod *4)-(2* \prod+4)}{4}$
Difference in area between $T_{1}$ and $(M_{1}+M_{2})$ = $\frac{\prod - 2}{2}$-$\frac{(\prod *4)-(2* \prod+4)}{4}$ = $0$

Answer (score 1):

It's about Venn diagrams.

Denote by $T$ the area of a $T_i\,$, by $S$ the area of a scraping tool, by $L=M_1+M_2$ the area of a lens, and by $K$ the area of the surrounding circle. Then
$$4T+4S+4L=K$$
and
$$S+2L={K\over4}\ .$$
From these two equations one at once gets $T=L$.